# Скачивание файла с FTP сервера

Tags: ftp, winsock, c++

Добрый вечер! Помогите понять почему не скачивается файл с FTP сервера... Что делаю:

```
sending("RETR f.xxx\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    getfile(DATA);
....

void getfile(SOCKET ds){
    char file[65536];
    int num;
    while(num=recv(ds, file,sizeof(file),1)>0){
        stream<<file;
        for(int i=0; i<65536; i++)
            file[i]='\0';
    }   
}
```

num=0, Что не так? При отправке RETR сервер присылает размер файла... Список файлов-каталогов принимаю по SOCKET ds, почему не приходит файл?

**UPD**

Не помогло:

```
void getfile(SOCKET ds){
    char file[65536];
    memset(file,'\0',65536);
    int num=0;
    unsigned int k=0;

    while(num=recv(ds, &file[0], sizeof(file),0)!=-1){
        if(num<0){
            cout<<"Error\n";
            break;
        }
        stream<<file;
        memset(file,'\0',sizeof(file));
        k+=num;file[num]='\0';
        cout<<"Recieved "<<k<<" bytes\n";
        if(k>100) break;
        }   
    }
....
в main
        stream.open("fff.avi",ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
        if(!stream){


            cout<<"Error open\n";
                getch();
                return 0;
            }

...

sending("RETR Файл.ххх\r\n",S);
    readServ(S);
    Sleep(2000);
    getfile(DATA);


    closesocket(S);  ///закрытие соединения
    closesocket(DATA); 
    WSACleanup();

    stream.close();
    getch();
```

Comment: А вы проверяйте не 0, а -1. Получили 0 - читайте дальше. И, кстати, `file` обнулять стоит `memset()`, а не циклом :)

Comment: 0 - это значит, что прочитано 0 байт. И конец файла это только в том случае, если вы уже прочитали ровно столько байт, сколько было в запрошенном файле. Тем более при работе по сети - никогда нельзя думать, что сколько запросили, столько вам и придёт.

Comment: Попробуйте в функции recv() в 4 аргументе указать 0, а не 1. Там флаги.
так же укажите file[num]=0;

Comment: @Alerr 
recv() заполняет буфер 'file' данными. И возвращает размер файла 'num'. 

file[num]=0 устанавливает терминирующий нуль для данного буфера. Который обозначает конец массива. 

Что означает последний цикл(for(int i=0; i<65536; i++)
)?

Что конкретно не получается? 
Что возвращает recv?

Comment: @manking, при чём тут конец массива, это что, C-строка? А если там первые 1896 символов - нули?

Comment: На команду LIST всё приходит, и файл по идее аналогично на этот же сокет и порт должен приходить?

Comment: @klopp 
Ну я строки принимал. Для бинарных данных тогда нужно работать с 'num'.

@Alerr 
зачем нули нужны в 'file'?

Comment: ну, мы запишем в память кусок кода типа 6574677644XXXXX, где XXX может быть всё что угодно, а когда ставим везде конец строки и записываем данные, то получаем 6574677644'\0' <- терминирующий ноль-строка кончилась... Как думаете, почему переменная file постоянно пустая???

Comment: Вы не на file, а на num смотрите. Если она возвращает 0 или меньше значит есть ошибка. 

Вызовите функцию WSAGetLastError() чтобы посмотреть в чём проблема.

printf("recv ошибка: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

Затем посмотрите соответствие ошибки [здесь][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: printf("recv ошибка: %d\n", WSAGetLastError()); возвращает о, говорит, что нет ошибки... Ну а размер файла =0 байт... Всегда приходят нули...